# How to refresh a list with an ons-carousel when ons-lazy-repeat detects a change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I have an ons-list which ons-list-item has the ons-lazy-repeat delegate.
Every ons-list-item has also an ons-carousel element with two indexes (0 and 1).

If I use a for loop to splice the array that is bound to the ons-lazy-repeat delegate the list will be changed to remove the items that were removed from the array but the ons-carousel index stays the same

Example:

```
<ons-list>
   <ons-list-item id="myList" modifier="chevron" class="item" ons-lazy-repeat="myDelegate">
      <ons-carousel swipeable auto-refresh style="height: 72px; width: 100%;" initial-index="0" auto-scroll>
         <ons-carousel-item class="list-action-item" ng-click="doThis()">
           Some random text
         </ons-carousel-item>
         <ons-carousel-item class="list-action-menu" ng-click="delete(elementId)">
           Remove all items like this one
         </ons-carousel-item>
      </ons-carousel>                 
   </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

The delete function is a javascript for loop that will go through the array associated with myDelegate and remove items that don't match the elementId

Example:

```
for (var i = $scope.myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var currenElement = $scope.myArray[i];
        if(currenElement.elementId === elementId){
            $scope.myArray.splice(i,1);
        }
};
```

Which works absolutely fine, the  gets updated and the items are visually removed from the list.

The ons-carousel index however stays 1 for element i of the array, which means that if the element i gets removed the element i+1 in the list that becomes element i will change the index to 1.

an example is available at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJOgoa
Try to drag to the left any of the elements and press on delete: you will see that the element gets removed but element i+i is now showing delete (the ons-carousel index="1" instead of 0)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view is fixed with `prev({animation: 'none'})` before removing the element:

```
$scope.remove = function(index) {
  $scope.carousel[index].prev({animation: 'none'});
  $scope.myArray.splice(index, 1);
};
```

And well, in your Codepen the delete function is triggered twice. That was a bug but it's now fixed in the latest build of Onsen UI. Working here: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/ByMmwE

**Edit:**
Created an [issue on Github](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/533) about this.

Comment: That's awesome Fran. Thanks a lot for the prompt response. I assume that I can just verify the changes here https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/c2226c4c711cc85b77e002503b8ce0804d9d363d/framework/directives/carousel.js and integrate the diff in my local onsenui.js?

Comment: Apparently, this bug is not related at all to ons-carousel, but to something bigger. You can check in this link another similar problem without carousel: http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/yyZPMY
Just write something in an input and delete it :/